# c# how to scan members date and how to find the oldest one?

Tags: c#

my code looks like that. Take a look.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace U1_15
{
class Student
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    //What should i use for a date??                    /// ///    ///
    public int StudId { get; set; }
    public int Course { get; set; }
    public int MobileNumber { get; set; }
    public bool Freshman { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    List<Student> ReadFile()
    {
        List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"studentai.txt");
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            string[] values = line.Split(' ');
            string lastname = values[0];
            string firstname = values[1];
            //Date!!!???                          ///////////////////
            int studid = int.Parse(values[3]);
            int course = int.Parse(values[4]);
            int mobilenumber = int.Parse(values[5]);
            bool freshman;
            if (values[6] == "Fuksas")
            {
                freshman = true;
            }
            else
                freshman = false;
        }
        return students;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
}
}
```

I have this data on file. [image: file]

Take a look at comments where i left. How to scan student's birthdate? And how to write a method that finds from all students the oldest one ?
Also should i change date format ?

Maybe i should delete dots in date ? Or what should i do to make better ?

I changed format to YYYY-MM-DD. What now ? Is it good?

```
   public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
```

Comment: Your format is `"yyyy.MM.dd"`, parse a string with that format into a DateTime.  Then you can sort

Comment: You want to use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_DateTime_ParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_System_Globalization_DateTimeStyles_). Also, how do you represent names with spaces in them?

Comment: If you have a choice, dates in text files should be in YYYY-MM-DD format, which is an ISO standard (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DateTime` for the date:

```
public DateTime DoB { get; set; }
```

Reading the date from your text file:

```
DateTime dob = DateTime.Parse(values[2]);
```

This seems to work for your case, but I'd definitely change the supplied date format if you have any control over the supplied data file whatsoever.

**Other things you should look at.**

First off, this

```
    bool freshman;
    if (values[6] == "Fuksas")
    {
        freshman = true;
    }
    else
        freshman = false;
```

can be simplified to

```
bool freshman = (values[6] == "Fuksas");
```

If, however, the casing of *"Fuksas"* ever differs for any reason - someone wrote *"fuksas"* instead, for example - the above will evaluate to `false`. 
So I'd further modify it to read

```
bool freshman = (values[6].ToLower() == "fuksas")
```

**Sorting**

Try something like

```
List<Student> sortedList = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.DoB).ToList();
```

and then grab the first entry in the list.

**Other Problems**

As stated in the comments, you will run into problems if anyone has a first or last name with a space in it - it's going to throw the order of everything else out.

To counter this, I'd really go with `csv` (comma separated values) as your file format instead - splitting a string on spaces isn't a good idea with first and last names.

Comment: Using To lower or ToUpper for a case insensitive string comparison is not a good idea. In English and a handful of other languages it works ok, but many languages have multiple possible upper or lower case equivalents to a character, or may consider different lower case characters as equal. Rather use the Equals overload and pass in the desired stringcomparison. For example, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase.

Answer (score 0):

I'll show you how find the oldest one manually (just to you see how works):

```
public DateTime GetOldestBirthDate()
{
    DateTime birthDate = DateTime.Now;

    foreach (var item in List<Student>)
    {
         if (birthDate < item.birthDate)             
                birthDate = item.birthDate;
    }

    return birthDate;
}
```

But, there are many ways to do this, for example: see [Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/linq-in-csharp).

I hope I helped you.

Comment: It isn't valid but the structure of this code helped me.